# Function is retuning undefined before promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, vue.js

I have a vue program that is using a service to get products from an API call.

```
getProducts() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(function (response) {
        return response;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

In the vue page that I need to call this I make the call in the created() hook like so:

```
  created() {
    //this returns a promise
    productservices.getProducts().then(response =>{
      this.products = response.data;
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    .finally(() =>{
      consol.log("All done!");
    })
  },
```

I can call the function no problem however it's running the .then() and returning Undefined. Why is this happening? How do I fix?

Comment: return before axios

Comment: There is nothing being returned from getProducts.... Should have been an error in your console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getProducts() {
    return axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
}
```

Try this instead.

Comment: Thank-you! How come this works but what I was doing wasn't?

Comment: This returns a promise. 

return response;  //this doesn't return a promise. Probably a json.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async/await

```
async getProducts() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        return response
    } catch(e) {
        // Do something with the error
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```